# getHeaderField("WWW-Authenticate") giving improper value in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I'm building a client for an api that uses http digest access authentication for authentication. I have studied the rfc to know the setup the required response headers and this works well on my emulator. Problem however is when I test on my phone (nokia E5), I found out that getting the www-authenticate header from the returned headers doesnt get the full value

[code]

```
// c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url) and other declarations

String digest = c.getHeaderField("WWW-Authenticate");

System.out.println(digest); // gives only: Digest
//no realm, qop and others
```

[/code]

I'm I doing something wrong or it is from the phone? What are my other options?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem in some `nokias`, and yes, it is a bogus `HttpConnection` implementation ... I suggest you to try creating a new `header` from the `server` side with a `base64 encoded WWW-Authenticate-encoded header` and using it instead, or you can do it the hard way and implement the whole `HttpConnection` from scratch ...